# ~ in ~site/_catalogs/masterpage/m.master is ignored

Tags: site-collection, url, token

I've received a WSP where the contained pages reference the master page as shown in the title.  The pages are deployed to a folder under the Site (ie http://app.contoso.com/PagesFolder/welcome.aspx).  It throws a FileNotFound error saying /PagesFolder/site/_catalogs/masterpage/m.master does not exist.

Where is the problem?  Is that as expected or is there something I need to configure to make the token work?

Comment: With which property do the page reference the master page?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `MasterPageFile` property is being set correctly and you could set any master page from gallery e.g. `MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master"`.

example usage in a Page layout:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage" MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/v4.master" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid=”SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>
```

Update:

There are different ways you can refer the master page in your page layouts:

- This is a relative or absolute path to a master page. Relative
  locations are based on the page instance's location - i.e.
  `"../_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master"` will find custom.master in the
  current SPWeb's master page gallery, which may or may not be the
  top-level site's master page gallery.
- Site-Relative Master Page `~site/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master.`
- Site Collection-Relative Master Page `~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/custom.master.`

Comment: Here's the Page Directive: <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~site/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomDefault.aspx" Inherits="MyApp.Welcome" Title="Welcome" %>

Comment: Your pages are created under a sub-folder "PagesFolder" and the `MasterPageFile` directive looks for the master page in the following path: `"/PagesFolder/site/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomDefault.master"` which definitely is not a valid path. Could you please also make sure that CustomDefault.master is present in the master pages gallery?

Comment: I have updated my post with different techniques to refer master page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which helped me in one of my scenario, of an Office-365 Site. Using the below URL I could refer the root-site master-page:
~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/<master-page>.master